# Issue with date time for cron job task

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I am working on a auto listing website and i am stuck at some logic behind how to get the dates right.

I have created a sql fiddle for the database
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e111e/3

I want to run a cron every day at 12 AM and i want to email the users whoselistings which are going to expire (ignores already expired ones) in a day but there must be a 24 hour difference between them as I want to tell them minimum 24 hours in advance that there listing is going to be expired. Also it should select only those listings which are going to be expire after one day only and not more than 1 day.

Here is what i tried so far

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(expiry_date, '%b %d %Y %T') AS expiry_date, DATEDIFF(expiry_date, NOW()) AS days_left FROM `test` WHERE DATEDIFF(expiry_date, NOW()) = 1
```

but it is also selecting which are going to expire in less than 24 hours.

Please help me with it.

EDIT
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have figured out this. Tell me guys if its correct or not.

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(expiry_date, '%b %d %Y %T') AS expiry_date, DATEDIFF(expiry_date, NOW()) AS days_left, HOUR(TIMEDIFF(expiry_date, NOW())) as hours FROM `test`
```

WHERE
DATEDIFF(expiry_date, NOW()) = 1 AND HOUR(TIMEDIFF(expiry_date, NOW())) > 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's `datediff` only takes into account the actual days, not the hours. Try to work with `TO_SECONDS` and take the difference as seconds.

UPDATE: and this is the code which works with the fiddle:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(expiry_date, '%b %d %Y %T') AS expDate,
  to_seconds(expiry_date) - to_seconds(NOW()) AS seconds_left
FROM `test`
WHERE
  to_seconds(expiry_date)- to_seconds(now()) <= 86400
  -- AND ... (only include non-expired entries)
```

Comment: thanks mate for the help. How about the query i have added? Do you think it is correct in its way as well? See n my edit

Comment: Not sure, but splitting the day and the hour values can always be a bit tricky. Why bother, why not just take the absolut value (e.g. in seconds) and use that for comparison?

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy. Your solution is effective but TO_SECONDS is available for MYSQL > 5.5. So I will use it in case the client is having > 5.5 version of msyql

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to [create an event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html):

```
CREATE EVENT EXIPRIYALERT 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY DAY AT '00:00:00' STARTING FROM  '2013-02-04'
DO 
  ---
```

For your query try this: [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

`TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,Now(),expiry_date)`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(expiry_date, '%b %d %Y %T') AS expiry_date, 
DATEDIFF(expiry_date, NOW()) AS days_left 
FROM `test` 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,Now(),expiry_date) = 86400
;
```